# Is there a performance difference between using Cypher and java API in Galaxybase?

Tags: graph-databases

I am new to Galaxybase and use Galaxybase with a relatively small amount of data, and there is no significant difference when using the Cypher and Java APIs.

Is there any actual difference in performance between Cypher and java API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are differences. Cypher queries are supported for the purpose of compatibility with neo4j. The limitations of Cypher syntax itself can lead to inefficient queries in some cases.

For example, its `(point)-[edge]-(point)` formulation naturally matches the dfs traversal approach, and is not applicable to the bfs traversal approach. Many graph traversal query application scenarios, if you use the dfs way will cause a lot of repeated iterative access, and not very efficient.

We specifically provide the bfsMaster method in the java api interface for bfs traversal queries, the speed can be much higher.